# Why does Git know my name when it is not configured?

Tags: git, configuration

I discovered that I haven't configured the `user.name` variable in Git: `git config user.name` prints nothing (also with `--system` or `--global` or `--local`).

My full name is also not contained in the output of `env`, only my login name, which is different.

Nonetheless, all my commits are attributed to my real first and last name.

How does Git know it?

---

Clarifications:

- My full name is contained in the `GIT_COMMITTER_IDENT` and `GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT` variables shown by the `git var -l` command. (I guess my question would then be: How did it get there?)
- I'm talking about a local repository. However I have other repositories on the same computer which are cloned at Github.
- I'm using a Debian system.
- My full name is contained in the output of `getent passwd`.

Comment: It's probably the user name for your computer.

Comment: Show output of `git var -l`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Okay, my name is in there. But how? Could you explain how that works in an answer?

Comment: Does your `/etc/passwd` file (if on Linux/Unix) contain your real name for your user ID? If so, that's where git is reading it from.

Comment: On Windows git use your account full name if `user.name` is not configured.

Comment: Yep, it's getting it from `/etc/passwd` (which is what `getent passwd` uses), as [I suspected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244336/why-does-git-know-my-name-when-it-is-not-configured?noredirect=1#comment67751832_40244336). Sounds like you answered your own question!

Answer (score 3):

It might be the case that you have environment variables set:

> The final creation of a Git commit object is usually done by
>   git-commit-tree, **which uses these environment variables as its primary
>   source of information, falling back to configuration values only if
>   these aren’t present.**
>
> GIT_AUTHOR_NAME is the human-readable name in the “author” field.
>
> GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL is the email for the “author” field.
>
> GIT_AUTHOR_DATE is the timestamp used for the “author” field.
>
> GIT_COMMITTER_NAME sets the human name for the “committer” field.
>
> GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL is the email address for the “committer” field.
>
> GIT_COMMITTER_DATE is used for the timestamp in the “committer” field.
>
> EMAIL is the fallback email address in case the user.email
>   configuration value isn’t set. If this isn’t set, Git falls back to
>   the system user and host names.

Source: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables

Comment: That's good to know, but none of these environment variables are set in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Unless specified in the Git configuration or in environment variables, Git will try to look up the username in the password file. The lookup is performed in the [`fmt_ident`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3ef7618e616e023cf04180e30d77c9fa5310f964/ident.c#L369) function.